# part not changing position roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I scripted a chat code detector in Roblox; I wanted to move an object (Elevator) to a specific position. The object does not move at all.

Things I have tried:

- Using CFrame to move the part instead of Vector3
- Keeping the part in the right position but disabling its scripts until I activate it
- Rewriting the script entirely in case it was a problem with the rest of the script

However the strangest thing of all:
At the bottom of Roblox Studio there is a bar that allows you to execute commands. When I run the exact piece of code that moves the object inside that bar, it moves. I do not know what is even happening.

```
local message='thestars'
function onChatted(msg,recipient,speaker)
    local source=string.lower(msg)
    if (msg==message) then
        game.Workspace.Elevator.Position=Vector3.new(99,-57,72)
        script.NOISE:Play()
        game.Workspace.radio.Radio.Union.Sound:Pause()
        while true do
            game.Workspace.bruh.Transparency-=.025
            wait()
        end
    end
end
function onPlayerEntered(newPlayer)
    newPlayer.Chatted:connect(function(msg,recipient) onChatted(msg,recipient,newPlayer) end)
end
game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(onPlayerEntered)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're chatting the *exact* string that's stored in `message`, i.e. correct case and no additional whitespace?

Comment: yes, the other things that the script does (make bruh visible) work just fine

Comment: I have this exact ".Position = Vector3.new" line in something I made and it works perfectly fine. My guess is that the surrounding code does not work. I can't really tell, to be honest, as I've never used anything related to chat.

Comment: as i said in the above comment; everything else in the script works exactly as planned. its just that line.

Comment: I don't see why, as that exact line works perfectly fine. Are there any errors or warnings?

Comment: not a single error or warning coming from the code.

Answer (score -1):

I did this by making a local script so that when the player chats "thestars", it fires a remote event to the server which does the action. Try that:

***Local script:***

```lua
local checkMessage = function(msg,recipient,speaker)
local message='thestars'
if msg == message then 
game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild(urthing):FireServer()
end
end
game.Players.LocalPlayer.Chatted:Connect(checkMessage)
```

***Server script:***

```lua
local myFunction = function()
    local source=string.lower(msg)
          game.Workspace.Elevator.Position=Vector3.new(99,-57,72)
        script.NOISE:Play()
        game.Workspace.radio.Radio.Union.Sound:Pause()
        while true do
            game.Workspace.bruh.Transparency-=.025
            wait()
        end
end
game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("thingyremote").OnServerEvent:Connect(myFunction)
```